# How can I pass a function parameter as a switch statement case value?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I am testing out switch statements in JavaScript and wanting to write one into a function for repeated execution.

I have been writing a basic function that takes either "male" or "female" as parameters, and logs one or the other to the console: "its a boy!" or "its a girl!", respectively.

```
function checkGender(gender){
    gender = "";
    switch (gender){
    case "male":
     console.log("it's a boy!");
     // have also tried using a return statement.
     break;
    case "female":
     console.log("it's a girl!");
     break;
    }
   }

    checkGender("male");
    // => should return "it's a boy!".
```

Expected: Invoking the function should return log statement to the console.

Actual Results: The console returns "undefined" as a value.

Comment: because you are empty the gender with `gender = "";`

Comment: You're not returning anything from `checkGender`, not even the result of `console.log()` (which coincidentally returns undefined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the `gender` value supplied to function by setting `gender=''` inside the function block. Based on the new `gender` value (which is empty), there is no case present and hence nothing in the console. Do not reset the `gender` value supplied to your function and it will work:

```js
function checkGender(gender) {
  switch (gender) {
    case "male":
      console.log("it's a boy!");
      // have also tried using a return statement.
      break;
    case "female":
      console.log("it's a girl!");
      break;
  }
}

checkGender("male");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variable `gender` to nothing `""`, therefore the case function will not see male or female, and will thus return nothing, or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The first instruction of your function affects an empty string to the `gender` parameter. Thus, none of the cases matches.

By the way, the `checkGender` function does not return anything. It only performs a `console.log` (if one case of the switch matches). Its return value will always be undefined.

Comment: I intended the first line within the function to serve as a default case value. How can I do so in the switch statement. 

(If my question is unclear still, I mean to ask how can I write an "else" statement for any other case other than "male" or "female"?).

Comment: By adding a "default" case in your switch statement.

Comment: Ah apologies! Here is a prime example of how not reading documentation could make a fool of a SO user.